# How to make canonical full/path/with/category/product-url?

Tags: seo, canonical

Question again. Sorry, cant find the answer :( Magento 1.9. I have several same pages:

```
1) domain/category/subcategory/product-page
2) domain/category/product-age
3) domain/product-page
```

When I use canonical configuration - I get domain/product-page as canonical. But I need FULL url domain/category/subcategory/product-page canonical. Or 404/301 from second and third type to first

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that - certainly not if SEO is of any value - that's because with the full path including categories and subcategories in them products that you have get duplicated several times with different url, even if you have every single product in one category and one subcategory they'd get duplicated just with the category in the url and the category or the sub category. Google doesn't like this so neither page will rank.

You want to use the internal functionality within System => Configuration => Catalog => Search Engine Optimization and set “Use categories path for product URL’s to “no”.

Product urls will then just display as domain.com/product.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done out of the box Magento but there are several extensions which can help you achieve this because even if you set **System => Configuration => Catalog => Search Engine Optimization and set “Use categories path for product URL’s to “yes”** then also Magento is going to set the path as **domain/product-page** because you have the products in multiple categories (main category and sub category). Here is the extension which can be used to fix the very mentioned problem in your question. Hope it helps

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-canonical-urls-for-category-product-and-cms-pages.html